# How are these two components different?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

Is one of these better than the other? What's the difference? They seem to be interchangeable

```
component
{
    property name="some_thing" type="string" value="";
}
```

vs

```
component
{
    this.some_thing = "";
}
```

Comment: The `this` scope is essentially public, so it can be modified by things outside the component, the `property` can't.  Its scope and access is more restricted. Plus, properties have a lot more features  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfproperty.html

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense. And I'm glad you pointed me to the doc. I couldn't find it because I didn't think of looking up the cf tag version.

Comment: Yeah, you often have to resort to that because the cfscript docs are .. better... but not up the level of the cfml docs. One nice feature of properties is using them to auto generate getters and setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**cfproperty**

Post CF8, 'cfproperty' allows one to set an implicit setter/getter.

It is also used in the creation of web services & ORM applications and has a vast array of configuration properties:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfproperty.html

**Setter/getter**

**com/foo.cfc**

```
component accessors='true' { 

    // set properties & variables above any component methods

    property name='bar' type='string';
    this.setBar('foo');

    function init(){
        return this;
    }

}
```

**Within a template 'foo.cfm':**

```
foo = new com.foo();
WriteDump(var=foo.getBar());
// foo
```

**'this' scope**

The 'this' scope can be accessed both internally & externally to the component.

**com/foo.cfc**

```
component { 

    // set properties & variables above any component methods

    this.bar = 'foo';

    function init(){
        return this;
    }

}
```

**Within a template 'foo.cfm':**

```
foo = new com.foo();
WriteDump(var=foo.bar);
// foo
```

**'variables' scope within a component**

The variables scope within a component cannot be accessed from outside the component.